# oracle sum limited value, extra to other variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

Query:

```
select sum((out_time+0) - (in_time+0))*24 man_hours 
from emp a,time_sheet b 
where a.SUPERVISOR='43561' 
  and a.EMP_ID=b.EMP_ID;
```

Sample data in table

```
emp_id    in_time              out_time
40716   08-07-2016 09:00    08-07-2016 18:00
40716   07-07-2016 09:00    07-07-2016 18:00
40716   06-07-2016 09:00    06-07-2016 18:00
60383   06-07-2016 09:00    06-07-2016 18:00
60383   07-07-2016 09:00    07-07-2016 18:00
41223   07-07-2016 09:00    07-07-2016 18:00
41223   08-07-2016 09:00    08-07-2016 18:00
```

Result: Sum of differences from above query is 45

difference between time in each row is 9 hours.

Requirement : I want only <=8 hours to sum up. >8 hours should be as other value.

Current 9*5= 45, required 8*5 = 40 and extra 5

I tried with decode, I am getting some weird results, actually I am not getting any idea in mind. Pointing out in right way would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: This isn't too clear to me.  Could you show us sample input and output in the form of tables?

Comment: added some sample data. Thanks for looking into it. :)

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: if i sum up all the diff in time then I get 63 i.e 7 rows * 9 diff= 63, I require 7 rows *8 and >8 should be collected  as other value. Like val a=56 and val b=7. so 63 hours should break up in that way. hope understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your basic query.
There is one row for every employee for every day, time spent regular and time spent overtime (if there was any).

```
WITH MY_TABLE AS  -- Dummy data, leave this out on your enviroment
(
SELECT 40716 AS ID, TO_DATE('08-07-2016 09:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') AS TIME_START, TO_DATE('08-07-2016 18:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') AS TIME_END FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 40716, TO_DATE('07-07-2016 09:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'), TO_DATE('07-07-2016 18:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 40716, TO_DATE('06-07-2016 09:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'), TO_DATE('06-07-2016 18:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 60383, TO_DATE('06-07-2016 09:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'), TO_DATE('06-07-2016 18:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 60383, TO_DATE('07-07-2016 09:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'), TO_DATE('07-07-2016 18:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 41223, TO_DATE('07-07-2016 09:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'), TO_DATE('07-07-2016 18:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 41223, TO_DATE('08-07-2016 09:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'), TO_DATE('08-07-2016 18:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL)
SELECT -- Actual query
  ID,
  LEAST (8, TOTAL_TIME) AS REGULAR_TIME, -- MIN of actual time and 8 hours
  CASE                                   -- If  he worked less than 8 hours,
      -- OT is 0, otherwise actual-8
    WHEN TOTAL_TIME > 8
    THEN TOTAL_TIME - 8
    ELSE 0
  END AS OVER_TIME
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ID,
      (TIME_END - TIME_START)*24 AS TOTAL_TIME -- Oracle date returns days,
      -- multiply by 24 to have hourse
    FROM
      MY_TABLE
  );
```

Result looks following

```
ID      REGULAR_TIME    OVER_TIME
40716   8               1
40716   8               1
40716   8               1
41223   8               1
41223   8               1
60383   8               1
60383   8               1
```

You can nest this query under another one and perform whatever you like, for example, group by id so you get total regular and over time in given time frame per empoyee.

Or sum it up, without any grouping to fulfil your original requirement.

```
SELECT
  SUM(REGULAR_TIME),
  SUM(OVER_TIME)
FROM(
-- nest previous select
);
```

Comment: prefer `UNION ALL` to simple `UNION` if ordering/ deduplicating of output isn't required.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started:

```
WITH
Timesheet_raw (emp_id, in_time, out_time) AS (
  SELECT 40716, '08-07-2016 09:00', '08-07-2016 18:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 40716, '07-07-2016 09:00', '07-07-2016 18:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 40716, '06-07-2016 09:00', '06-07-2016 18:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 60383, '06-07-2016 09:00', '06-07-2016 18:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 60383, '07-07-2016 09:00', '07-07-2016 18:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 41223, '07-07-2016 09:00', '07-07-2016 18:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 41223, '08-07-2016 09:00', '08-07-2016 18:00' FROM DUAL
),
Timesheet (emp_id, in_time, out_time, length_of_shift) AS (
  SELECT
    emp_id
    , TO_DATE(in_time, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
    , TO_DATE(out_time, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
    , (TO_DATE(out_time, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') - TO_DATE(in_time, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')) * 24
  FROM Timesheet_raw
)
SELECT
  emp_id, LEAST(length_of_shift, 8) regular, GREATEST(length_of_shift - 8, 0) overtime FROM Timesheet
;
```

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: It worked used the query from above, thank you for your efforts and time :)